# How does division "distribute"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would be the expansion of 
$$a/(b\times c)$$
I can figure this out by writing it out as a fraction or by using examples.
I am more interested in how this plays out just using the divison symbol.
e.g. for just multiplication, $a\times(b\times c)=a\times b\times c$

Comment: $a/( b \times c) = a \times \dfrac {1}{( b \times c)}$.

Comment: $a/(b \times c) = (a/b)/c$

Comment: See [Multiplying fractions](http://www.aaamath.com/fra66mx2.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have multiplication and division, it works exactly the same way as if you had had only addition and subtraction:
$$
a-(b+c) = a-b-c \iff a/(b\times c) = (a/b)/c
$$
(I like to use the brackets for repeated division, because division isn't as universally left-to-right as subtraction is). We can reason about it as follows: Whatever $a/(b\times c)$ is, we'll call it $x$. Then we have
$$
x = a/(b\times c)\\
(b\times c)x = a\\
(b\times c)x/b = a/b\\
cx = a/b\\
cx/c = (a/b)/c\\
x = (a/b)/c
$$
And we see that $a/(b\times c)$ and $(a/b)/c$ are the same thing.

Comment: Makes sense. Still, what is there to stop me writing the expression as  $a/b/c$ and then evaluating $b/c$ first? It seems the parantheses are vital or is there some convention when doing divison I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: @quadfire You will find many people here (and elsewhere) who adhere to the convention that divisions (nd multiplications) are evaluated left-to-right (just like addition and subtraction: for $a-b-c$ people would think you crazy if you first evaluated $b-c$ and then subtracted the result from $a$). I personally do not follow that convention and instead use brackets to make it clear what I mean. So when I see $a/b/c$ I consider that ambiguous exactly for the reason that you mention.